# Filter list of tuples depending on if second element is found in another list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to create a list starting from two lists:

```
list_one = [1, 2, 3]

list_two = [('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2), ('rab', 5)]
```

Output list should be made of tuples where the second element is found in list_one.

E.g.

```
[('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2)]
```

Stupid and (I think) inefficient way I've thought of:

```
for i in list_one:
    for j in list_two:
        if i == j[1]:
            final_list.append(j)
```

Any suggestion for an efficient version (thinking of bigger lists)?

Comment: `S = set(list_one) ; [e for e in list_two if e[1] in S]`

Comment: @mozway: Can you explain the need/desire for using `set`?

Comment: @Scott `in` is `O(n)` for a list, `O(1)` for a set, if you repeat the operation many times (here using a loop) this avoids quadratic complexity

Comment: @beforesunset666 yes, which is literally what I wrote above with different (more explicit) names :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

```
>>> list_one = [1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> list_two = [('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2), ('rab', 5)]
>>>
>>> list_one_unique_elements = set(list_one)
>>> [(first, second) for first, second in list_two if second in list_one_unique_elements]
[('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2)]
```

Comment: It is inefficient to repeatedly search in a list, a set should be used

Comment: @mozway So a better solution would be

`filter_set = set(list_one)`  
`final_list = [tup for tup in list_two if tup[1] in filter_set]`  

Edit: you pointed out exactly this in another comment, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Python gives neat syntax for checking if an element is `in` a list:

```
result = []
for pair in list_two:
    _, value = pair
    if value in list_one:
        result.append(tuple)
```

Comment: I think this only swaps the inner `for` loop with `in`. I think the other suggestion with the use of `set()` should be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, very true. While both work, please look to the answer from @Abdul Niyas P M for the more efficient solution