# Filter list of tuples depending on if second element is found in another list in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a way in haskell to filter  out tuples if second element is found in another list ?

I want same as this but in haskell: [Filter list of tuples depending on if second element is found in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72113937/filter-list-of-tuples-depending-on-if-second-element-is-found-in-another-list)

For example:

list of keys

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

list of tuples

```
[('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2), ('rab', 5)]
```

result

```
[('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `elem` function:

```
Prelude> keys = [1, 2, 3]
Prelude> a = 5
Prelude> a `elem` keys
False
Prelude> a = 3
Prelude> a `elem` keys
True
```

If `filter` can be used to filter a list based on a function:

```
Prelude> filter even [3, 6, 8, 1]
[6,8]
```

How can you write a lambda that determines if the second item in the tuple is in your list of keys?

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
tuples = [('foo', 2), ('bar', 3), ('oof', 2), ('rab', 5)]

result = filter (\tpl -> ...) tuples
```